# jQuery and MooTools Conflict together

Tags: jquery, mootools

I'm using the below code with jQuery, which works

```
$('.s_switcher').hover(function() {
   $(this).find('.s_options').stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
},function() {
   $(this).find('.s_options').stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
});
```

After replacing the code and adding MooTools and Jquery, there is no result and the code doesn't work.

```
//no conflict jquery
jQuery.noConflict();
//jquery stuff
 $jQuery('.s_switcher').hover(function() {
        $jQuery(this).find('.s_options').stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
 },function() {
        $jQuery(this).find('.s_options').stop(true, true).slideUp('fast');
})(jQuery);
```

Please let me know if some one can help, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `jQuery(...)` instead of `$jQuery(...)`. Or you can create `$jQuery` as an alias to `jQuery` like this: `$jQuery = jQuery.noConflict()`.
Also, remove `(jQuery)` at the end of your code - it doesn't do anything.